# Multiple word search page in django

Tags: django, post, get

Basically, I need to create a search page in django which has input fields say rollno, name, class, teacher's name . A user might enter any or all of the details and click search. It should go to another html template and view the details of the students matching it to the details entered.

I have an html page search.html and results.html.

search.html

```
<input type="text" name="roll_no" class="form-control" placeholder="roll no" >
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name" >
<input type="text" name="class" class="form-control" placeholder="class" >
<input type="text" name="teacher_name" class="form-control" placeholder="teacher's name" >
```

results.html
It should show only the details of the students that matches with the input text entered in the search.html and not all

```
Roll_no:<span class="float-right">{{post.roll_no}}
 Name:<span class="float-right">{{post.name}}
 Class:<span class="float-right">{{post.class}}
 Teacher's_name:<span class="float-right">{{post.t_name}}
 Father's_name:<span class="float-right">{{post.fa_name}}
```

Please do help, the videos and tutorials I have looked so far show searching which search for say posts and show them in the same page itself.

Answer (score 0):

The two pages seems to be right, in the backend you can write django function like, where you read the form data if there is a post request else it will render search.html page. I assume you dont want to use a database the task is just to read and display.

```
def returnResults(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         rollNo = request.POST['roll_no']
         name = request.POST['name']
         class_ = request.POST['class']
         teacherName = request.POST['teacher_name']
         post = {"roll_no" : rollNo, "name":name, "class":class_, "teacher_name":teacherName}
         return render(request, 'search.html',{"post":post})
    else: 
        return render(request, 'search.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find out about [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/)! Which will also let you have the filter form at the top of a display of what it found.